# What is the proper way to call this._super() inside a ViewState?

Tags: ember.js

I have the following StateManager:

```
App.wrapperView = Em.ContainerView.create();
App.wrapperView.append();

App.states = Em.StateManager.create({
    rootView: App.wrapperView,
    initialState: "loading",
    loading: Em.ViewState.create({
        view: App.LoadingView,
        enter: function() {
            this._super()  // _super is not defined.
            // other stuff goes here
        }
    })
});
```

Therefore, i cannot maintain the adding behavior.

How should i proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
enter: function(manager, transition) {
  this._super(manager, transition);
}
```

More info here: http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.StateManager&src=false

Comment: Or you can do `this._super.apply(this, arguments)` to make it dynamic - or in coffeescript, `@_super(arguments...)`

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this:

`this._super(...arguments);`

it's less typing and gets transpiled to

`this._super.apply(this, arguments);`